# Equal not Equal php

Tags: php

The first one with equals will work and I would expect that. But the second is not working as expected.

```
    $nicktest = "new"; 
 if ($nicktest == "new" || $nicktest == "fun" || $nicktest == "norm" || $nicktest == "pvp")
        {
            $odpoved = "Ok it works.";
            echo $odpoved;
            return;
}

        $nicktest = "new"; 
 if ($nicktest != "new" || $nicktest != "fun" || $nicktest != "norm" || $nicktest != "pvp")
        {
            $odpoved = "Ok it works too why?";
            echo $odpoved;
            return;
}
```

Comment: Your second if will always be true. Think about it: How can something be equal to `new` and `fun` at the same time?!

Comment: To check if something is equal to one in a list of items, use `or`/`||`, to check if it is NOT something, use `and`/`&&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 4 conditions get the following evaluation:

false, true, true, true

Now,

```
if (false || true || true || true) {
    // Code block is actually evaluated
}
```

If you would happen to have:

```
if (false || false || false || false) {
    // Code block wouldn't be evaluated
}
```

Under this scheme, at least one `true` condition would get the code to be evaluated

Comment: Thanks this makes a lot more sense i normaly dont have problems like this. I dont know how could i stuck on this :D

Comment: I dont know why but i switched the or to and and it still dont work it doesnt matter if the $nicktest is "new" "fun" or something random.. if ($nicktest != "new" && $nicktest != "fun" && $nicktest != "norm")